# Regular Expression - Match String Not Preceded by Another String (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find a regular expression that will match a string when it's NOT preceded by another specific string (in my case, when it is NOT preceded by "http://"). This is in **JavaScript**, and I'm running on Chrome (not that it should matter).

The sample code is:

```
var str = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com www.stackoverflow.com';
alert(str.replace(new RegExp('SOMETHING','g'),'rocks'));
```

And I want to replace SOMETHING with a regular expression that means "match www.stackoverflow.com unless it's preceded by http://". The alert should then say "http://www.stackoverflow.com rocks", naturally.

Can anyone help? It feels like I tried everything found in previous answers, but nothing works. Thanks!

Comment: Read about "negative lookaheads".

Comment: Techically, this whole string is not preceded by `http://`; should it be replaced as a whole?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<!http:\/\/)www\.stackoverflow\.com/: Invalid group

Comment: @AssafHershko So then `var str = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com www.stackoverflow.com www.stackoverflow.com'; alert(str.replace(new RegExp('SOMETHING','g'),'rocks'));` would produce "http://www.stackoverflow.com rocks rocks",

Comment: @JackThor The way it's described, it should produce just 'rocks'.

Comment: Sorry, the comment above was the error I get if I try my understanding of a negative lookbehind, i.e. (?<!http://)

Comment: JS regex engine doesn't support lookbehinds.

Comment: @raina77ow I think he means block of character in the string

Comment: So there's no way of doing this in JavaScript? Sound crazy :(

Comment: All I'm looking for is a RegEx that allows me to match string XXX if it's not preceded by YYY, in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

As JavaScript regex engines don't support 'lookbehind' assertions, it's not possible to do with plain regex. Still, there's a workaround, involving `replace` callback function:

```
var str = "As http://JavaScript regex engines don't support `lookbehind`, it's not possible to do with plain regex. Still, there's a workaround";

var adjusted = str.replace(/\S+/g, function(match) {
  return match.slice(0, 7) === 'http://'
    ? match
    : 'rocks'
});
console.log(adjusted);
```

You can actually create a generator for these functions:

```
var replaceIfNotPrecededBy = function(notPrecededBy, replacement) {
   return function(match) {
     return match.slice(0, notPrecededBy.length) === notPrecededBy
       ? match
       : replacement;
   }
};
```

... then use it in that `replace` instead:

```
var adjusted = str.replace(/\S+/g, replaceIfNotPrecededBy('http://', 'rocks'));
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fjY9g/).

Answer (score 0):

raina77ow's answer reflected the situation in 2013, but it is now outdated, as **[the proposal for lookbehind assertions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) got accepted into the ECMAScript spec in 2018.**

See [docs for it on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#other_assertions):

> | Characters | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | `(?<!y)x` | **Negative lookbehind assertion:** Matches "x" only if "x" is not preceded by "y". For example, `/(?<!-)\d+/` matches a number only if it is not preceded by a minus sign. `/(?<!-)\d+/.exec('3')` matches "3". `/(?<!-)\d+/.exec('-3')` match is not found because the number is preceded by the minus sign. |

Therefore, you can now express "match `www.stackoverflow.com` unless it's preceded by `http://`" as `/(?<!http:\/\/)www.stackoverflow.com/`:

```js
const str = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com www.stackoverflow.com';
console.log(str.replace(/(?<!http:\/\/)www.stackoverflow.com/g, 'rocks'));
```

Answer (score -1):

This also works:

```
var variable = 'http://www.example.com www.example.com';
alert(variable.replace(new RegExp('([^(http:\/\/)|(https:\/\/)])(www.example.com)','g'),'$1rocks'));
```

The alert says "http://www.example.com rocks".

Comment: It works, but not in the way you think it does. Basically, as character class regex operator is used, you're just replacing a sequence of any symbol that's not in 'htps:/()|' range, followed by `www.example.com`. It'll give you a lot of false positives, first, and it's plain redundant, second.